# Create a stack bar chart, using r

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization

I would like to create a stacked bar chart, in which stack all the bars into one by percentage. However, I can only create a normal bar chart. Seek for your help.

```
df$pecent <- paste0(round(100* group1$count/sum(group1$count)), "%")

ggplot(group1, aes(fuel_type, y= pecent, fill=pecent)) + geom_bar(postion= position_stack(), stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE)
```

df:
[image]

output:
[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput` instead of images? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach with the `mtcars` data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(gear= as.factor(gear)) %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(perc= n/sum(n),
         id="1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=perc, fill=gear))+
  geom_col(position = "stack")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels= scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `x = ""` with `position = "fill"` to stack all the values to one bar. To get a percentage axis you could use `scale_x_continuous` with percent labels. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(group1, aes(x = "", y= count, fill=fuel_type)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels= scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data:

```
group1 <- data.frame(fuel_type = c("DIESEL", "LPG", "PETROL", "PETROL/ELECTRIC"),
                 count = c(9,14,704,3),
                 pecent = c("1%", "2%", "96%", "0%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with `str_extract` to extract and convert to numeric the numeric values in column `pecent`:

```
library(stringr)
ggplot(group1, aes(x = "", 
                   y = as.numeric(str_extract(pecent, "\\d+")),
                   fill = fuel_type))+ 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")+
  labs(y = "%", x = "")
```

Data (thanks to @Quinten):

```
group1 <- data.frame(fuel_type = c("DIESEL", "LPG", "PETROL", "PETROL/ELECTRIC"),
                 count = c(9,14,704,3),
                 pecent = c("1%", "2%", "96%", "0%"))
```